# Simple stuff for c programmers

Tags: c

To which of the following is

```
myFunc( int x )
```

equivalent to?

```
a) myFunc( int *x );
b) myFunc( int x[] );
c) myFunc( int x[10] );
```

Please explain your answer..

Comment: Did you forget the homework tag?

Comment: What is this? Homework or quiz for SO answerers?

Comment: This is a question asked to me in one of the interviews of a company... I was confused so I asked... Whats there in it to decrease my reputation for??

Answer (score 3):

To none because `x` is a pointer to `int` in all three function prototypes.